# Moving the AppDelegate class into a library project

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

So I am trying to take the bulk of my code from an application project and place it in a library project (dll) for reuse.  I have moved my AppDelegate.cs class from the main application project and placed it in the library project.  I then updated my Register attribute on my AppDelegate class to reflect the move.

```
namespace DLLNamespace
{
    [Register ("DLLNamespace.AppDelegate")]
    public partial class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then in my app project in the Main.cs file I have changed to the following

```
public class Application
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UIApplication.Main(args, null, "DLLNamespace.AppDelegate");
    }
}
```

All of this works great in the iOS simulator, but as soon as I run in debug on an iPhone 5 I get the following error on Main

```
Objective-C exception thrown. Name: NSInternalInconsitencyException Reason: Unable to            instantiate the UIApplication delegate instance. No class named DLLNamespace.AppDelegate is loaded.
```

Again, it works great in the iOS simulator and I can step into the code in the AppDelegate class in the library project, but bombs on an actual device.

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that it's not really a good design to put an `AppDelegate` in a class library because it is both iOS and UI specific.  Can you move the bulk of the code in your `AppDelegate` to a more generic all-purpose class?

I try to keep my `AppDelegate` small, and sometimes I will even "link-in" the file if the app delegate is identical. I would do this for a "free" and "pro" version of the same app.

Comment: Normally I would agree with you, but the nature of this app and it's distribution scheme lends itself very well to the AppDelegate being in a separate library.

Comment: Can you just "link-in" the same file to the rest of the projects? I suspect Xamarin might not support a main `AppDelegate` in a class library.